# Kali linux, nothing appears after I logged in

Tags: debian, installation, kali-linux

I just installed kali linux in dual boot with windows 10 on my laptop.

The installation went fine until I had to log in in the GNOME GUI.
After I enter the correct credentials, the dialog boxes just disappear and nothing happens.

Until now I tried to:

- reinstall after checking the md5 sum
- reinstall without the graphical mode
- reinstall without the network so it won't download maybe some unadapted driver
- tried to disable the GPU card from BIOS but can't with this pc
- tried to switch to other tty but neither it just does nothing or it switches to a black screen but can't type anything

I also tried to disable GUI using the kali live (which is working normally) on the USB and directly accessing the file of my kali installation.

I'm out of ideas and need help.

Comment: If Kali can boot directly from an ISO file through grub, that might be a lot easier than installing - just copy the iso to the hard drive somewhere & make a grub entry (some "multiboot" USB's do that, in some form). I'm not sure if Kali can do that though, but Ubuntu & most Debian's can...

Comment: What surprise me is that i've installed  kali linux in dual boot on two other pcs without any problems, never had issues using it, it just feels like any debians based distros with preinstalled penetation testing tools. So based on my experience I dare to disagree with the first comment. On other post i've read this issue was gpu related but since i dont have access to another tty i can't even check that, guess i will just try to install install debian.

Comment: @music2myear, don't link people to that. It's poor. Do you have any actual reference to Kali being designed for USB? There is a group of users in the Unix&Linux se (that you linked to) that insist it's designed for usb. This is a contradiction to what the developers say for general use.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/download-kali-linux-revealed-book/